# Extracting telephone numbers

Tags: regex, pcre

i want to extract telehpone numbers but its only matching `Place C` but not matching `Place A` and `Place B`. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

**Regex**

```
(.+?)\s*(\d+.*Singapore\s+\d{6}\b|\d+.*S\d{6})\b(?!(\.+?)\s*)(\+65[\d ]*)
```

**Edited Text**

```
Place A
2 Bayfront Avenue Galleria Level #B1-01 Singapore 018972 Tel: +65 6634 9969

Place B
23 Serangoon Central #B1-10 Singapore 556083 Phone: 6634 7787

Place C
1 Northpoint Drive South Wing #B1-107 Singapore 768019 6481 3433
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the 6-digit number and the telephone number, there can be a label, so you need to account for that and consume it somehow. One example to do that, is to allow any character to optionally be there, that isn't a `+` sign, like so:

```
[^+]*
```

In the context of your regex, that makes it:

```
(.+?)\s*(\d+.*Singapore\s+\d{6}\b|\d+.*S\d{6})\b(?!(\.+?)\s*)[^+]*(\+65[\d ]*)
```

Which [now matches](https://regex101.com/r/ZYhcUG/1) all three cases.

**Edit:**

Based on the updates, I modified the regex to [match all six cases](https://regex101.com/r/dJDOwR/1):

```
(.+?)\s*(\d+.*?Singapore\s+\d{6}\b|\d+.*?S\d{6})\b[^+0-9]*((?:\+65)?[\d ]*)
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Thanks for your help. So `[^+]*` helps to consume any optional characters?

Comment: @scorezel789 - Yes, it's a [`character class`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches whatever characters are between `[]`, but in this example, the caret `^` negates it, so it means match any character that is NOT in the list `[^+]`, and then we repeat it 0 to an unlimited number of times with `*`.

Comment: I understand better now. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Do you mind me asking how do i extract only the 8 digits instead of starting with +65 `(\+65[\d ]*)` regex?

Comment: @scorezel789 - Move the parenthesis so it no longer includes +65 - `\+65([\d ]*)`

Comment: i mean i want to ignore the +65 as well

Comment: @scorezel789 - Make it optional: `(?:\+65)?([\d ]*)`

Comment: I've made slight edits to the text input to see if you get what i mean. I only want the 8 digits. Thank you for your help i really appreciate it!